# Render custom header in element-ui to show bootstrap tooltip?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, element-ui

I try to render a bootstrap tooltip (https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tooltip/) within a header of an `element-ui` table.

I use the custom header render method:

```
<el-table-column
  v-for="(column, index) in headers"
  :render-header="renderHeader"
/>
```

The following code renders as expected except of the id which is missing. For debugging purposes I added a class which renders as expected:

```
renderHeader(h, { column }) {
  return h(
    'div',
    {
      id: `tooltip-target__${column.property}`,
      class: 'some-class'
    },
    [
      column.label,
      h(
        'b-tooltip',
        {
          attrs: {
            triggers: 'hover',
            target: `tooltip-target__${column.property}`
          }
        },
        column.label
      )
    ]
  );
},
```

Comment: Is your `column.property` value unique across all rows of your table? And are you including Bootstrap and BootstrapVue's CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` needs to be defined inside the `attrs` object:

```
renderHeader(h, { column }) {
  return h(
    'div',
    {
      attrs: {
        id: `tooltip-target__${column.property}`
      }
      class: 'some-class'
    },
    [
      column.label,
      h(
        'b-tooltip',
        {
          attrs: {
            triggers: 'hover',
            target: `tooltip-target__${column.property}`
          }
        },
        column.label
      )
    ]
  );
},
```

I found a good example in the documentation:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth